# Eloquent fatal error: argument passed not the right instance

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

I'm in the process of building an endpoint system in PHP using Slim and Eloquent, as outlined [here](http://www.slimframework.com/news/slim-and-laravel-eloquent-orm). When running it in my local dev, the code below fails with what appears to be a Fatal Error based on what the methods are expecting

```
// Load Eloquent
$connFactory = new \Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory();
$conn = $connFactory->make($settings);
$resolver = new \Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolver();
$resolver->addConnection('default', $conn);
$resolver->setDefaultConnection('default');
\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setConnectionResolver($resolver);
```

The actual error is:

```
[Wed Aug 13 10:31:44 2014] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to
Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory::__construct() must be an instance 
of Illuminate\Container\Container, none given, called in
/Users/outsider/application/index.php on line 22 and defined in
/Users/outsider/application/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php on line 25
```

There's not a whole lot of guidestones in the docs about this. Any ideas on the possible cause?

Comment: The error is clear. You have to pass an `Illuminate\Container\Container` instance as parameter when you do `$connFactory = new \Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory();`

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Manolo for pointing out what I was missing. I needed to declare a Container and initialize it:

```
$container = new Illuminate\Container\Container;
$connFactory = new \Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory($container);
$conn = $connFactory->make($settings);
$resolver = new \Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolver();
$resolver->addConnection('default', $conn);
$resolver->setDefaultConnection('default');
\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setConnectionResolver($resolver);
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an easier way to use Eloquent outside Laravel. You can use Capsule:

```
/* Setup Eloquent. */
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;

$capsule = new Capsule;
$capsule->addConnection([
    "driver"    => "mysql",
    "host"      => "localhost",
    "database"  => "example",
    "username"  => "root",
    "password"  => "t00r",
    "charset"   => "utf8",
    "collation" => "utf8_general_ci",
    "prefix"    => ""
]);

$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Comment: Also solved my problem with Slim framework. Works like a charm! :)