# Slim 3 Eloquent initialization error Argument 1 must be Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

Disclosure: This is my first Slim app

I've tried to use Eloquent with Slim 3, but I can't seem to get it work. I've installed everything with composer, followed the install guide on the site.

When I try to use my User model (which extends the Eloquent model) I get a fatal error:

> *Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on null in ****\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 3280*

My appConfig looks like this:

```
$config['db'] = [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => '****',
    'database'  => '****',
    'username'  => '****',
    'password'  => '****',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
];
```

which I pass to the app according to the documentation:

```
$app = new \Slim\App(["settings" => $config]);
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['db'] = function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    $settings = $container->get('database');
    $capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
    $capsule->addConnection($settings);
    $capsule->setAsGlobal();
    $capsule->bootEloquent();

    return $capsule;
};
```

My User class looks like this:

```
class User extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {}
```

I've found a workaround on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411954/how-to-trigger-eloquent-manager-in-slim-3-1-dependency-injection) like so:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;

    class User extends Eloquent {
            public function __construct(Manager $capsule, array $attributes = [])
        {
            parent::__construct($attributes);
        }
    }
```

But if I override the constructor according to the port I get a different error:

> _Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Up\models\User::_*construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager, none given, called in ****\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 644 and defined in ****\models\User.php on line 14*

I'm stuck now. Please help

Comment: `$capsule->addConnection($container->get('database'));` != `$capsule->addConnection($config['db']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289627/eloquent-fatal-error-argument-passed-not-the-right-instance), but it seems a little out of place. I just had to init Eloquent separetly like so:

```
$capsule = new Capsule;
$capsule->addConnection($config['db']);
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

this way the `$container['db'] = function () {}` part is excluded, but now everything works

EDIT (for comments): the whole part now looks like this:

```
$app = new \Slim\App(["settings" => $config]);
$container = $app->getContainer();
/*$container['db'] = function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    $settings = $container->get('database');
    $capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
    $capsule->addConnection($settings);
    $capsule->setAsGlobal();
    $capsule->bootEloquent();

    return $capsule;
};*/

$capsule = new Capsule;
$capsule->addConnection($config['db']);
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Comment: The problem is that the container only executes the code in the funciton if its ever called.... So if you have a model, and nothing ever calls db eloquent is never started :)

Comment: Didn't get  what you are saying with "had to init Eloquent separetly " , can you add more details plz?

Comment: @Biguá i just did ;)

Comment: Since then, the documentation was updated with better examples, and now its clear, that the `$capsule->bootEloquent();` call was missing (from the original doc).